# Should I add an answer that is a clearer explanation of existing info to an old question?

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm very new to SO and have just started learning Python. I have a question about etiquette. I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488052/my-python-code-does-not-run-a-print-statement-at-the-end-of-a-loop) that has already been answered by some people, and although the answers do answer the question, I have struggled with the same thing (while loops are hard when you're new!) and I think my answer would be easier to follow for someone on my level.

Should I write a new answer, which will contain pretty much the same info as earlier answers but just be more elaborate? Or should I comment on existing answers? Or should I not post at all, because it's belittling to think the OP needs more explanation?

Comment: If you think your answer is correct and adds value to the post, then by all means post it and explain why you think this answer will be better for future audience who might stop by. When you provide answer, you are providing it  for countless users to come. Many of them might have issues understanding it so add all the details you can. They only add value to your answer.

Comment: There are actually badges for this if you answer an old question with no activity and get up votes for your well constructed answer. See [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23996/does-it-make-sense-to-answer-old-questions) & [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185181/is-it-worth-my-time-answering-old-posts) question for more info.

Comment: And expect the Meta Effect: proper posts by proper users linked on Meta get a rush of upvotes, while improper posts which are linked to (as in "I came across THIS crappy answer...") get downvoted to hell. Welcome, and good to see you in the former category;)

Comment: For what it's worth, the question isn't that old. It was posted yesterday. But it seems the Meta Effect is working well.

Comment: @Ellesedil Yes, what a warm welcome. It's certainly helped me feel more invited to answer questions in the future. I don't want to 'clutter' SO with bad answers, but at the same time I really want to contribute :). Thanks for all of your help, everyone!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Don't be afraid to answer an old question with information that you wish to provide.  Things that are good to contribute to old questions are:

- A new approach
- A new take on the problem
- An alternative solution to the ones provided
- A simpler explanation

If you feel that you can accomplish at least one of those, your new answer will be welcomed.  Just remember:

- You'll be competing with older answers, so your answer will be judged more critically, and advance through the Late Answers review queue
- You shouldn't repeat anything that has already been expressed; that is, don't take an existing answer and repost it
- Be sure that your answer is clear, concise, contains well-formed English, and any code provided is well-formatted (especially with Python, since whitespace matters)

Comment: New [technology/language functionality](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0315/) not available when the original question was asked can often merit a new answer; usually they fulfil one of Makoto's first four points.

Comment: on "shouldn't repeat anything" -- each answer should be the complete answer and therefore the answers may overlap.